# selenium - javascript - how to open a different url?

Tags: javascript, selenium, href, selenium-ide

I've got `the_id` to be 31

How can I go to that url with js in selenium?

I have been trying:

```
store # not sure command to use here.  Not "open" as that open up this window.
javascript{window.location.href = "/districts/${the_id}"}    
dummy
```

but `${the_id}` is not being interpolated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it actually was being interpolated OK

It was just the log showed the ${the_id} but the url used the real value.

It was hard to see as I am testing error pages which make the actual url hard to see.